# How can I get started as a freelance programmer?

Tags: .net, freelancing

Assume that I know zero about freelancing, but I am a good .NET programmer.

I want to start freelancing.

How would I get started?

Comment: It is hard really you will hard work and people will not pay. can go with freelancing sites to take experience good luck

Comment: Belongs to (programmers.stackexchange.com) as it [lists](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) "Freelancing and business concerns" between its topics.

Comment: Do you have your own product? Or you want provide a service? The question is very broad and prolly gonna be closed.

Comment: I used and still use craigslist to build my portfolio. As you get more work for your portfolio it is easier to get better/more work. Now I have a business and advertise in other media.

Answer (score 6):

It all starts with who you know. Do you have friends (in industry) that are starting project they don't have the staff for? Do you have a particular skill you can provide to these teams?

Your professional network is your biggest asset.

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to create an online portfolio website with examples of your work, etc, that you can show to clients.

After that, its a matter of getting in touch with companies that could be looking for you. You could either use offline contacts the way that people here have suggested, or you could also look on sites like VWorker.com , oDesk.com , etc.

Comment: just to keep you up with the news: vworker is now bought by freelancer.com

Answer (score 1):

As its already been said, contacts are your first step so, use them and/or make them. Going to conventions on a certain topic of interest may lead you to know people in the field that may need or know people that need programmers.

Try to create a digital footprint, so people that might need a goot .NET programmers know that you are available. Join freelance places such as mentioned in this Question made here [Freelance programming sites](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/51591/10785)